# Move particular table from Production to Development: Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Need to create a ADF pipeline to selectively restore certain/particular table from production to development environment.
The table is in Synapse and both are different environments.

Below **BOLD** statement is pre-requisite:

**Due to security reasons, we can't use single user account to move data, need to make it configurable so we can change tables on demand.**

Will be great help,
Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain what is the problem you are facing? Is the text "Due to security reasons" an error message you get, and if so when are you getting it?

Comment: @ChenHirsh This is pre-requisite that we can't use single user account to do this. Rest I'm new to ADF so trying to work this out on how to move data from prod to dev. 
Move data to ADLS and then load, still figuring out which approach to use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create 2 necessary linked services in ADF to connect to both the production Synapse Analytics and development environments.
Here is how you can create a [linked Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-linked-services?tabs=data-factory).

Once you have created the linked service for PROD and DEV enviroment, you will see the configurations as below:
**Prod:**
[image]

**Dev:**
[image]

Next you need to configure datasets for PROD and DEV environment,  datasets in ADF for the source (production)
destination (development) table. You can find more about datasets [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-datasets-linked-services?tabs=data-factory)

While creating the ADF pipeline.
You will need endpoints to search for your synapse enviorments you can find them in the synapse workspace overview like below.

[image]
[image]

If you unselect the copy activity, in the bottom panel you will find a tab for parameters
[image]
If you want to make the pipeline flexible and reusable, you can define parameters for the table names.

[image]
At the Pipeline runtime it will ask you for the table name.
[image: enter image description herehttps://i.imgur.com/mmuoDCY.png]

Use the trigger or Debug your pipeline.
[image]

**Output:**
[image]

**Note:** Anybody who have access to Azure subscription in which the ADF has been created will have option to customise tablename while running the ADF pipeline to   **move the data**.